# What should I change in this function for grayscale images to work

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this C++ function to create an image from multiple images:

```
      Mat imageCollage(vector<Mat> & array_of_images, int M, int N )
{
  // All images should be the same size
  const Size images_size = array_of_images[0].size();
  // Create a black canvas
  Mat image_collage( images_size.height * M, images_size.width * N, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0, 0, 0 ) );

  for( int i = 0; i < M; ++i )
  {
    for( int j = 0; j < N; ++j )
    {
      if( ( ( i * N ) + j ) >= array_of_images.size() )
        break;

     Rect roi( images_size.width * j, images_size.height * i, images_size.width, images_size.height );
      array_of_images[ ( i * N ) + j ].copyTo( image_collage( roi ) );
    }
  }

  return image_collage;
}
```

My program is supposed to create an image collage from multiple images and it works for RGB images but not when I convert them to grayscale. I tested separately the functions and I think it's this one that creates the problem. This is the error I get:

```
OpenCV(4.5.0-dev) /home/csimage/Documents/opencv-repos/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:254: error: (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function 'copyTo'

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *but not when I convert them to grayscale*? Do you mean when `array_of_images` contains grayscale images?

Comment: Seems like your function creates a black RGB canvas of type `CV_8UC3` - correct for an 8 bit, 3 channels image. However, grayscale images are `CV_8UC1`, as they only have 1 channel.

Comment: @eldesgraciado  ohh okay so it should work after I change that right?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes